# Editable choice field/drop down box in Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am very new to Django. I want to create a editable drop down box.  After searching I found the below code to create the dropdown list.

```
Choices1 = [("0", _("0")), ("1", _("1")),("2", _("2"))[("3", _("3"))]

_list =  forms.ChoiceField( choices=choices1,label=_("ListExample"),required=False)
```

It displays the drop down box. But this is not an editable field. It does not allow me to edit the value , it just allows me to select. I want to make this dropdown/choice filed as editable box.

Thanks,
Kalai

Comment: sorry, what do you mean with 'editable box'?? can you select or write the input?

Comment: I need to let users select an item from a dropdown list, but also allow them to instead enter any text, even if it doesn't match an item in the list.

I want drop down box similar to below one.     http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/form_widget_editable_select/form_widget_editable_select.html

Comment: How you solve this problem?! I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do:

```
Choices1 = [("0", _("0")), ("1", _("1")),("2", _("2"))[("3", _("3"))]

options = (value for key, value in Choices1 )

list =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs{'selectBoxOptions':';'.join(options)})),label=_("ListExample"),required=False)
```

in your html, you could try:

```
<form>
    {{form.as_p}}
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    createEditableSelect(document.forms[0].myText);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: the solution is now available with html5 which allows editable dropdown list.
And so with Django: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791625/1937033