# Is there a Django admin form field that allows for a list of optional suggested values instead of strictly validated choices?

Tags: django, django-admin

Given a model with a CharField, I'd like admin users to be able to pick from a list of suggested values for the CharField, however unlike [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices) I'd like to allow alternative free-text input.

Is there such a type of form-field I can configure for my ModelAdmin for this model's CharField?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question, please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783275/django-form-with-choices-but-also-with-freetext-option

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django form with choices but also with freetext option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783275/django-form-with-choices-but-also-with-freetext-option)