# Get form values (foreign key field) in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to add the foreign key options to a select input but don't know how to get it. I want to make the same as using the form generated by Django, but with my own HTML.
The form is for creating a new "patient".

This is are the foreignkeys from my patient model:

```
ubication = models.ForeignKey(Ubication, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
supervisor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

And this is the patient form:

```
    class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Patient
            fields = ['dni', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'birth', 'risk', 'status', 'ubication', 'supervisor']
            widgets = {
                'dni': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'birth': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'risk': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
                'ubication': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
                'supervisor': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'})
            }
```

For example, here I want to add the supervisors from the supervisor model to vinculate it to the patient model:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" required name="supervisor" id="id_supervisor">
                    <option selected>Select supervisor</option>
                    {% for f in form.supervisor %}
                    <option value="{{f.id}}">{{f.first_name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to make choice field where the user selects the supervisor based on one of the supervisors available, right?

You can create the choices in your form script.

on `PatientForm` do the following:

```
# SUPERVISORS is the model where the supervisors are stored in your code
# you will have to modify it
from .models import SUPERVISORS

CHOICES = [ (supervisor.id, supervisor.get_full_name())
            for supervisor in SUPERVISORS.objects.all() ]

class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
   supervisor = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
      class Meta:
      # leave the rest as is
```

If you want to tweak this you can get more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/).