# When editing a model in django, it outputs pk foreignkey and not the desired field?

Tags: python, django

How to output `name` field and not `pk` in form?

The `pk` number of the `foreignkey` of the model is displayed in the input field. The input field is a `ChoiceTxtField`.

**forms**

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = 'include/_forms_orders_datalist.html'

    def format_value(self, value):
        if value == '' or value is None:
            return ''
        if self.is_localized:
            return formats.localize_input(value)
        return str(value)

class ChoiceTxtField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget=ListTextWidget()

class SimpleOrderEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service = ChoiceTxtField(queryset=Service.objects.order_by('-used'))
    device = ChoiceTxtField(queryset=Device.objects.order_by('-used'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(SimpleOrderEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        status_excluded = ['','-']
        self.fields['service'].choices = [(k, v) for k, v in self.fields['service'].choices if k not in status_excluded]
        self.fields['device'].choices = [(k, v) for k, v in self.fields['device'].choices if k not in status_excluded]

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ['device','service']
        widgets = {}
```

**include/_forms_orders_datalist.html**

```
<input id="ajax_input_{{ widget.name }}" list="{{ widget.name }}" autocomplete="off"
    {% if widget.value != None %} name="{{ widget.name }}" value="{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}"{% endif %}
    {% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>

    {% for group_name, group_choices, group_index in widget.optgroups %}
        {% for option in group_choices %}
            <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-warning text-dark" id="list-item-{{ widget.name }}" name="list-item-{{ widget.name }}">
                {% include option.template_name with widget=option %}</span>
        {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}

<datalist id="{{ widget.name }}">
    <optgroup label="">
    </optgroup>
</datalist>
```

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey('Service', default=1, on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT, null=True, verbose_name='Услуга', related_name='get_service')
    device = models.ForeignKey('Device', default=1,  on_delete = models.SET_DEFAULT, null=True, verbose_name='Устройство', related_name='get_device')

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Наименования услуги')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True, verbose_name='Устройство')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `__repr__` method to your `Service` class:

```
def __repr__:
    return str(self.name)
```

Comment: Try in your form:
`self.fields['service'].choices = [(v, k) for k, v in self.fields['service'].choices if k not in status_excluded]`

Comment: it too did not help((

Comment: what about `(k, v) for v, k`?